# How to select all option for search to show in the below table?

Tags: php, sql

I am creating the form to select all option to show in the below table, I want to search when I am selected the option show in the table. My part to do is let me to onchange "Transaction Type" then show the below table. How to function can let me to select all option to show in the below table? Hope anyone can give me example or edit in my coding to guide me how to do it. I want the output can follow my select date range and transaction type to show the table.

`transaction_history` file to show the frontend create the form and pass the data to the backend.

```
    <?php
 $system_user_type = $user_type;

     $lang = $_COOKIE["Language"];
   $new_cur_date = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($cur_date));
 require_once("language/lang_transaction_" . $lang . ".php");
    ?>

   <html>
  <head>
   </head>
     <body>


      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="box form-group">
                <header>
                    <h5><?php echo $language["LIST_TITLE1"]; ?></h5>
                    <!-- .toolbar -->
                    <div class="toolbar">
                        <nav style="padding: 8px;">
                            <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-default btn-xs collapse-box">
                                <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                            </a>
                        </nav>
                    </div><!-- /.toolbar -->
                </header>
                <section class="content">
                    <div class="col-lg-12  form-group" >
                        <label for="text1" class="form-group control-label col-lg-2"><?php echo $language['type']; ?>:</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <select id="select_type" class="form-group form-control required" onchange="show_table();">
                                <option value="transfer" selected><?php echo $language["transfer"]; ?></option>
                                <option value="withdraw"><?php echo $language["withdraw"]; ?></option>
                                <option value="upgrade"><?php echo $language["upgrade"]; ?></option>
                                <option value="register">Register</option>
                                <option value="receive"><?php echo $language["receive"]; ?></option>

                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-8"></div>
                    </div>
                       <div class="col-lg-12 form-group">
                            <label for="text1" class="form-group control-label col-lg-2">Date Range:</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-2">
                                <?php echo custom_period_opt(); ?>
                            </div>
                            <label for="text1" class="form-group control-label col-lg-2">Date Created</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-2">
                                <input type="text" class="form-group form-control datepicker" id="start_date" name="start_date" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" title="" value="<?php echo $new_cur_date; ?>" readonly>
                            </div>
                            <label for="text1" class="form-group control-label col-lg-2">To</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-2">
                                <input type="text" class="form-group form-control datepicker" id="end_date" name="end_date" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" title="" value="<?php echo $new_cur_date; ?>" readonly>
                            </div>
                        </div>
  <div class="col-lg-12" style="text-align:center; padding-bottom:10px; padding-top:10px;">
                <button id="search_button" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="search2_('search', 'bill_table', 'billing');">Search</button>  
                <button id="clear" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" onclick="clearData()">Clear</button>    
            </div>
                    <div class="" id="table_result">

                    </div>
                       </section>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

     </body>
     </html>




           <script>
                                $(function() {
                                   show_table();
                                    $("#select_type").on("change", function() {
                                        show_table();
                                    });
                                });
                                function show_table() {
                                    //alert(123);
                                    var select_type = $("#select_type").val();
                                    $.ajax({
                                        url: "?f=transaction_table",
                                        type: "POST",
                                        data: {
                                            select_type: select_type
                                        },
                                        before_send: function() {
                                            show_overLay();

         //$('#patient_result').html('');
                                        },
                                        success: function(data) { 
                                            hide_overLay('');
                                            //alert(data);
                                            if (data) {

      $("#table_result").html("");

  $("#table_result").append(data);
                                                // 
     $('.dataTable').dataTable();
                                            } else {
                                                alert("Please fill in the field.");
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                                }

      </script>

      <style>
       .myClass
     {
    display: none;
         }

       </style>
```

`transaction_table` file to show the backend function send to frontend page.Below is my coding:

```
          <?php
     $select_type = $_POST['select_type'];
  if ($select_type == "withdraw") {
   echo '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>';
        $i = 1;
        $select_transfer = 'SELECT * FROM withdrawal_record bp WHERE user_id = ' . $user_id . '  ORDER BY created';
        $arr_transfer = db_conn_select($select_transfer);
        foreach ($arr_transfer as $rs_transfer) {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' . $i++ . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . date('d-m-Y', strtotime($rs_transfer['created'])) . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $rs_transfer['withdraw_amount'] . '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
echo " </tbody>
     </table>";
   }elseif ($select_type == "transfer") {
      ?>
       <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>To Type</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        $i = 1;
        $select_transfer = 'SELECT * FROM transfer_history_bp WHERE user_id = ' . $user_id . '  ORDER BY created';
        $arr_transfer = db_conn_select($select_transfer);
        foreach ($arr_transfer as $rs_transfer) {
            if($rs_transfer['point_type']=="2"){
                $to_type="Register Point";
            }elseif($rs_transfer['point_type']=="3"){
                $to_type="Entertainment Point";
            }elseif($rs_transfer['point_type']=="4"){
                $to_type="Business Point";
            }
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' . $i++ . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . date('d-m-Y', strtotime($rs_transfer['created'])) . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $to_type . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $rs_transfer['total_amount'] . '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
        </table>
          <?php
        }elseif ($select_type == "upgrade") {
       ?>
       <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        $i = 1;
        $select_transfer = 'SELECT * FROM upgrade_point WHERE user_id = ' . $user_id . ' ORDER BY created';
        $arr_transfer = db_conn_select($select_transfer);
        foreach ($arr_transfer as $rs_transfer) {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' . $i++ . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . date('d-m-Y', strtotime($rs_transfer['created'])) . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $rs_transfer['total_amount'] . '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
         </table>
        <?php
      }elseif ($select_type == "register") {
    ?>
      <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        $i = 1;
        $select_transfer = 'SELECT * FROM transfer_history_rp WHERE user_id = ' . $user_id . ' and created between "2019-11-01 12:25:05" and "2099-11-01 12:25:05" and use_type=1 ORDER BY created';
        $arr_transfer = db_conn_select($select_transfer);
        foreach ($arr_transfer as $rs_transfer) {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' . $i++ . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . date('d-m-Y', strtotime($rs_transfer['created'])) . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $rs_transfer['total_amount'] . '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        ?>
      </tbody>
       </table>
        <?php
     }elseif ($select_type == "receive") {
?>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        $i = 1;
        $select_transfer = 'SELECT * FROM extra_point WHERE user_id = ' . $user_id . ' ORDER BY created';
        $arr_transfer = db_conn_select($select_transfer);
        foreach ($arr_transfer as $rs_transfer) {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' . $i++ . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . date('d-m-Y', strtotime($rs_transfer['created'])) . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $rs_transfer['total_amount'] . '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?php
  }
      ?>
```

Below is my output, this output just can follow what I select the transaction type to onchange to show in the table:

[image: Output]

Below is my database information:

[image: Database information]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then you need to include these additional parameters in your request as you already to with `select_type`.

First, get the additional values in the`showTable` function, also add them to the request data:

```
function show_table() {
    var select_type = $("#select_type").val();
    var start_date = $("#start_date").val();
    var end_date = $("#end_date").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "?f=transaction_table",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            select_type: select_type,
            start_date: start_date,
            end_date: end_date
        },
    // ...
}
```

then, receive the values in your PHP file like you already do with `select_type`:

```
<?php
    $select_type = $_POST['select_type'];
    $start_date = $_POST['start_date'];
    $end_date = $_POST['end_date'];
    // ...
```

Finally, you have to adjust your queries accordingly. As you already have `and created between "2019-11-01 12:25:05" and "2099-11-01 12:25:05"` in your queries, it's just a matter of replacing the hardcoded dates with the ones you received. **Do not forget to sanitize your input dates!** If possible use prepared statements.

**Note 1**: Your `script` and `style` tags are outside of the html part of your site. This is not valid. These tags belong into either the head or the body tag.

**Note 2**: There are whitespaces before your opening `html` tag. You may wan't to avoid this too, since it can trigger IE into quirks mode. Simply change this

```
?>

   <html>
```

to this

```
?><html>
```

Comment: I've tried you code and clicked the search button, it can't work.

Comment: What exactly did not work? Have you checked if the values were read in your JS?Have you check that you received the values in PHP? Have you checked the queries? Are there any error messages or is nothing happening? You will have to put in some effort yourself, we just try to help you get in the right direction here..